# Автоматическая сборка проекта при изменении кода

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

В docker-e новичок.

Есть стандартная сборка с create-react-app.

Хотелось бы спросить, как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении кода контейнера перезапускалась сборка?

К примеру в `App.jsx` я меняю код с

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

на

```
<h1>hello world zuzu</h1>
```

хотелось бы чтобы код обновлялся в `localhost`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./dashboard
    container_name: frontend
    command: npm run start
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment: 
      - PORT=3000
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i 

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Запуская через `docker-compose up --build`

Пробовал запускать через `docker-compose up --build --no-cache`

Также пробовал добавить эти настройки

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

к файлу `docker-compose.yml`, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет в этом CI\CD. Процесс может быть таким:

1. Вы коммитите изменения в репозиторий вашего проекта
2. Далее запускается процесс CI/CD, который обеспечивает билд и деплой проекта

Смотрите в сторону [Github CI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/about-continuous-integration) или [Gitlab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/)

Comment: Благодарствую! [символы]